# Game Scene Manager

Tags: scene

I'm starting to code my engine's Scene Manager, and after some research in the internet I've found (surprisingly) various posts **against** the use of a SceneGraph.

It does make sense, and the concept itself is quite old, so what are the alternatives and/or some examples of it?

Comment: You want a list of alternatives to scene graphs and examples of them? When you say "it does make sense" do you mean the concept of a scene graph, or the posts advocating not using scene graphs?

Answer (score 2):

What you are **probably** reading is that it's seen as a mistake to reuse a graphics scene graph as the managed scene data structure for the rest of the program to work with.

For a long while, back in the stone age, memory was tight and there was only one data structure holding a level together and it served rendering and game logic.  Now we have a little room to work with and performance and easier coding of more complex features means that we need and can use structures appropriate to the algorithms.

For example, a quadtree is great for graphics operations but it would be ridiculously bad if you needed a list of all active enemies.

Beyond that simple example I think that you need to really think about what you are asking and add a lot more detail (and a glossary) to the question before you'll get any replies useful to you.